# is there any open-source script like fontastic?

Tags: fonts, self-hosting

I searched a lot but I couldn't find and script like app.fontastic.me.
it is a custom icon manager which you can import svg icons and convert it to normal font icons and publish it as a CDN link. but it has some limitations.
I wanna ask is there any script like this but self-hostable?

Answer (score 1):

I asked AI and got the following list:

1. Fontello
2. IcoMoon
3. Material Design Icons
4. FontAwesome:

Hope that helps.

Comment: are they open-source or self-hosted?
for example having a site like theme using a docker container or something like that.

Comment: Fontello & IcoMoon provide you with the option to download the assets and host them on your own server. Material Design Icons & FontAwesome are limited in that regard. FontAwesome allows you to donwload if you opt for their pro paid tier.